# Creating a Table of Contents in which Figures and Tables are listed by Chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like create a table of contents in which the tables and figures that are referenced in each chapter are listed under each chapter heading. For example:

TOC

**1. Chapter 1**

1. Figure 1 - XX
2. Figure 2 - YY
3. Table 1 - XX
4. Table 2 - YY

**2. Chapter 2**

1. Figure 1 - AA
2. Table 1 - CC
3. Table 2 - DD

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: For some document classes, \chapter already adds a blank line using `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%`.  (Actually, \@chapter.)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite like your example but hopefully it may give you some ideas.

```
% tocfigprob.tex  SE 566735
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{First}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A FIGURE
\caption{A figure}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thefigure. A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
A TABUATION
\caption{A tabulation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thetable. A tabulation}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{An illustration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Figure \thefigure. An illustration}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `\addcontentsline` macro is used above to put stuff into the ToC. You can fiddle about with that to see what style of figure and table entries you can get in the ToC. Afterwards perhaps change the `\caption` macro to effectively use the `\addtocontentsline` appropriately.

If you want the figures to be listed before tables and with sequence numbers before them that is much more complicated.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful1